# replaceObjectAtIndex does not seem to be working

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

working with a basic objective c example here, tried to use replaceObjectAtIndex for an array and it doesn't seem to be working.

my code:

```
 NSMutableArray *myArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    [myArray addObject:@"First string"];
    [myArray addObject:@"Second string"];
    [myArray addObject:@"Third string"];

    NSString *newElement=[myArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"New object at index 1 BEFORE is %@", newElement);
    [myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"Hello"];
    NSLog(@"New object at index 1 AFTER is %@", newElement);
```

theoretically the output for newElement should now display "Hello", but it's still displaying "Second String"

output:

```
2012-05-30 11:21:16.638 cocoa lab[753:403] New object at index 1 BEFORE is Second string
2012-05-30 11:21:16.641 cocoa lab[753:403] New object at index 1 AFTER is Second string
```

please advise

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the new value from the array after replacing it

```
// ...
[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"Hello"];

/* ADD THIS */
newElement=[myArray objectAtIndex:1];

NSLog(@"New object at index 1 AFTER is %@", newElement);
```

At the moment you fetch the original string, replace the array's object, and print out the original string again.

Comment: hmm, thought that newElement was a pointer to the element 1 of the array, so when that element got changed, newElement would reflect it. Guess not. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: C style arrays work the way you describe. A pointer to the array, is just a pointer to the first element and then you can add some multiple of the size of the elements, to get a pointer to an element further down the array.  

Objective C `NSArray`s on the other hand, are objects. The elements in the array are also objects. And all pointers point to the actual objects, not some placeholder in the array.

Comment: @Live2Enjoy7 `newElement` is a local variable that contains a pointer to an object. If you don't reset the pointer to point to some other object, it's still pointing to the original one.

Comment: @Live2Enjoy: newElement is a pointer to the object @"Second string". There was also a pointer to that object in the array. When you changed the pointer in the array, that didn't change the other pointer. If you had altered the object itself (say, if it were a mutable string and you'd changed its contents), that would show up everywhere there was a pointer to the object. But assigning a new value to a pointer doesn't change any other pointers in your program.

Comment: @SveinHalvorHalvorsen The OP wasn't asking about the array itself, but about the local variable `newElement`.

Comment: @jlehr Yes, I understand that :-) Please read my comment and the one above me again. If it is still unclear what I'm trying to explain, please feel free to ask.

Comment: @Chuck: by using replaceObjectAtIndex am I not modifying the original array element? I thought I was since I specifically made it a NSMutableArray. Thanks for all the input

Comment: @SveinHalvorHalvorsen Let's assume `newElement` is of type `id`. Let's further assume that it's pointing to an element of a C-style array. Now change the value of the array element. Does `newElement` magically change to point to the new value?

Comment: @Live2Enjoy7: "Array element" is kinda vague. You are putting a new object in the array, which modifies the array. It does not modify the object that used to be in the array. There is no concrete thing called an "array element" for you to modify that will automatically pick up changes to the array. The phrase "array element" really just means "thing in an array." So in that sense, you're not modifying the array element — you're replacing it with a new one.

Comment: @jlehr Yes, if you grab the pointer to carray[2], and put a new value in the array, the pointer will now point to the new value. If you have something of type id in your c-style array, the pointer above will be a pointer to a pointer, a ptr**

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the value of `newElement` after calling `replaceObjectAtIndex:`, so add another line before logging the value the second time:

```
newElement=[myArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

**UPDATE 1**

And don't feel bad -- we've all done this to ourselves at one time or another.  :-)

**UPDATE 2**

By the way, a good way to avoid this kind of problem in general is to get in the habit of using separate local variables in these kinds of situations, for example, you could rewrite the code you posted as follows:

```
NSString *initialValue = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"New object at index 1 BEFORE is %@", initialValue);

[myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"Hello"];

NSString *newValue = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"New object at index 1 AFTER is %@", newValue);
```